# Appending JSON Object

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, elk

I am passing the below json string as input and I want to form ELK query dynamically based on the below json input, like three aggregations even if a new field comes inside the display field  then need to generate a nested ELK query based on the fields inside the array.

Input Query:

```
{
  "displayField" : ["eventInfo.deviceType", "eventInfo.appVersion", "eventInfo.os"]
}
```

Now based on the above fields like deviceType, appVersion and os the elk query will be like below

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "stateNameNested": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "eventInfo"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "deviceType": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "eventInfo.deviceType.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "appVersion": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "eventInfo.appVersion.keyword"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "os": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "eventInfo.os.keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to construct the ELK query dynamically in Java but the desired result doesn't come.

```
public List<String> getDeviceDetailsWithAppandOsVersions(DisplayFieldDTO displayFields) {
        logger.info("Aggregated fields....{}", displayFields.getDisplayField());
        List<JSONObject> fieldNameAggs1List = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        List<JSONObject> fieldNameAggs2List = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        List<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        RestClient restClient = userSegmentUtils.getElasticClientInstance();
        Request request = new Request("GET", INDEX_NAME + SEARCH_API);
        JSONObject elkQuery = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject aggs = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject stateNameNested = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject nested = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject fieldNameAggs = null;
        JSONObject fieldNameVal = null;
        JSONObject terms = null;
        JSONObject aggs2 = null;
        JSONObject fieldNameAggs2 = null;
        nested.put(PATH, EVENT_INFO);
        stateNameNested.put(NESTED, nested);
        aggs.put(STATE_NESTED, stateNameNested);
        elkQuery.put(SIZE, 0);
        elkQuery.put(AGGS, aggs);
        logger.info("Elk Query....{}", elkQuery);
        for (String displayField : displayFields.getDisplayField()) {
            fieldNameVal = new JSONObject();
            terms = new JSONObject();
            fieldNameAggs = new JSONObject();
            fieldNameAggs2 = new JSONObject();
            aggs2 = new JSONObject();
            logger.info("Display field....{}", displayField);
            String[] fieldName = displayField.split("\\.");
            logger.info("Field name...{}", fieldName[1]);
            fieldNames.add(fieldName[1]);
            terms.put(FIELD, displayField + "." + KEYWORD);
            fieldNameVal.put(TERMS, terms);
            fieldNameAggs.put(fieldName[1], fieldNameVal);
            fieldNameAggs1List.add(fieldNameAggs);
            fieldNameAggs2.put(AGGS, fieldNameAggs);
            fieldNameAggs2List.add(fieldNameAggs2);
        }
        logger.info("AggsList...{}", fieldNameAggs1List);
        logger.info("AggsList...{}", fieldNameAggs2List);
        JSONObject obj = null;
        int counter = 1;
        logger.info("Trye...{}", fieldNameAggs1List.get(1).append("appVersion", fieldNameAggs2List.get(2)));
        return null;

    }
```